# Are Athena settings specific to each user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

In AWS Athena, you can set the query result location via "Settings" on the upper right. Does this setting and others in the dialogue box affect all users of the account (see screenshot below)?

I know if I change the Workgroup, all users will see the changes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Are Athena settings specific to each user?

No. They are **specific to Athena service**. So any IAM user/role which has access to athena will see same parameters.

Thus, to separate different use-cases, teams and users you create different [workgroups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/manage-queries-control-costs-with-workgroups.html). You can use IAM permissions to control who can use a given workgroup.

Comment: I tried setting the "Query result location" just now. After I set it, I asked a colleague to see if he can see the same settings. He couldn't. I wonder if it takes a while to sync...

Comment: @rishai let him check it via a cli command, not via the GUI, the athena gui is really bad at managing / switching workgroups. There is nothing to *sync*, maybe he has something cached but this is unlikely for management endpoints.

Comment: @luk2302 Okay, let me find the CLI command for him to check. We did make sure we were looking at the same workgroup.